# How do you convert all values in a Range to text?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `Range` object referencing a column on a worksheet.  This column contains mixed datatypes (numbers, text, and a few other things).

I want to remove duplicates from the column:

```
rge.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:xlNo
```

but this does not correctly remove all duplicates due to the mixed datatypes.

I know that mixed datatypes are the problem because manually converting the cells using `TEXT($REF, "0")` before attempting to remove duplicates from a copy of those values is successful.

---

How can I replace all values in the range with their text equivalents?

I've tried the obvious:

```
rge = rge.Text
rge.Value = rge.Text
```

but without success.

---

Please note that iteration is *not* an option; I'm dealing with tens of thousands of rows of data, and the performance penalty for writing cells individually is far too high.  I need something which can operate on the entire range at once.

(If it turns out that iteration is the only solution, it will actually be faster to make a first pass using `.RemoveDuplicates`, sort the data, then manually take out the remaining ones in `n` time.)

---

EDIT: Additional information

If I copy and paste a subset of the range which does not contain duplicates, and then manually run Remove Duplicates on it, the duplicate values are removed.

However, if I copy a subset of the range which also contains numbers, then duplicates are *not* removed, *even though the duplicates are not themselves numbers*.

My guess (and this is only a guess) is that internally excel uses a different comparison algorithm for mixed-datatype values than it does for purely text values.

---

Minimum working example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1402749/dups.xlsx

Comment: Can you try (manually) inserting columns, formatting them as text, then copying and pasting (the values) into these columns. Then try removing the duplicates. If this works it could be put into code. Before this though, I would try running Remove Duplicates twice.

Comment: @AndyG - Thanks for the suggestion; I've updated the question with additional information based on that.  Removing duplicates multiple times doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't try to use the `RemoveDuplicates` method since it seems to not work for you anyways.

I use a dictionary object to do the dirty work and help ensure uniqueness.  Based on the (apparent) success of this example, I'm not sure you need to worry about converting values to text. This iteration uses the *values* only, and then re-writes to the range. If you require additional *formatting*, please clarify :)

```
Sub Test()
Dim d As Object 'Scripting.Dictionary
                ' requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime if you
                ' want to use early-binding
Dim rng As Range
Dim cl As Variant
Dim var As Variant

'#Define our range
Set rng = Range("A1:A22")
'#Store values in an array
var = rng.Value
'#Instantiate our dictioanry object
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'#store unique vals in the dictionary
For Each cl In var
    d(cl) = cl
Next

'#Clear the original range
rng.Clear
'#Put the unique vals in to the range
rng.Resize(UBound(d.Keys) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(d.Keys())

Set d = Nothing
End Sub
```

On the sample data, I end up with 17 unique values:

[image]

Comment: While there are some excel functions that are optimized for efficiency, the correct pure VBA solutions often seem to be the best

Comment: @psubsee2003 *especially* when dealing with very large ranges, if you can work with the arrays in memory only, it is usually much faster than manipulating the worksheet objects.

Comment: @DavidZemens - Thanks; this was my original approach, but sadly it is orders of magnitude slower than using worksheet objects.  The performance (and sanity) penalty for using VBA is high ;)  I think what I might do is run `RemoveDuplicates` first, then run the (much smaller) array through this.

Comment: *Thanks; this was my original approach*  <-- next time, you might consider adding this background information to your Q, so that we don't waste our time proposing solutions that you've already tried or are otherwise unsatisfied with... cheers.

Comment: Whoa, didn't see your post. I was testing on and on before posting to possibly resolve Excel memory issue since I got problem when dealing with more than 30k data when trying to return them to range without iterating. :D

Comment: @sapi `but sadly it is orders of magnitude slower than using worksheet objects`. I test the same approach as what David come up with and the speed is comparable to Excels RemoveDuplicates. I don't think performance is an issue with a few hundred millisecond difference.

Comment: @DavidZemens - sorry, I didn't think to mention that I'd tried this because it's the intuitive way of solving the problem.  I assumed the fact I was asking implied that it didn't work for me.  In retrospect that was really silly, so I apologise.

Answer (score 0):

> Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

I would think rge.NumberFormat = "@" would work

Comment: Sadly not.  I think the issue is that some of the problem values aren't numbers (eg, one is `145/B128/2`), so anything which deals with numbers alone might have issues.  Part of me wonders if excel is reading that as a date...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will provide the result you are looking for.  Insert this function into VBA editor.

```
Public Sub ConvertToText()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim a As Areas
    Dim v As Variant

    Set c = Selection
    Set a = c.Areas

    If a.Count > 1 Then
        ' IF DESIRED YOU CAN EXTEND THE LOGIC FOR MULTIPLE AREAS | CURRENT FUNCTION DOES NOT SUPPORT
        MsgBox "Select one continuous range.", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    v = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(c.Value))

    c.Clear
    c.NumberFormat = "@"
    c = v

End Sub
```

Comment: Updated to handle dates properly.

Comment: Is the idea behind this to rely on a side-effect of transposing the data?

Comment: It's leveraging the efficiency of the Transpose function to insert the values into a variant array.  The reason we are using it twice is so that we do not change the data orientation of rows of columns when we put the array values back into the range.  This is a common mechanism used by Excel VBA coders as it avoids the need to iterate through the range on operations such as this one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; unfortunately, it doesn't work.  Duplicates are still left in the data.  (Sadly I suspected as much, as the original source for the data was a variant array to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an issue with your use of the RemoveDuplicates syntax.

Try:

```
rge.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
```

I would recommend running the other code to first standardize the formats as text though.  This syntax worked fine for me.

Comment: No luck with that either, unfortunately.  I'm having the same problem using the UI, so I don't think it's an error in the calling code.  I added a MWE to the question, if you want to take a look.

Comment: I think somewhere the spreadsheet and data encoding may have gone awry.  I also had no luck at first with your spreadsheet.  This is how I got it to work. (1) Copy the column of cells and pasted into Notepad++. (2) Converted the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM. (3) Created a new Excel spreadsheet and formatted the cells as Text.  (4) Pasted the values from Notepad++ into the Excel file. (5) Ran the code above [first assigning rge = Selection].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why removeduplicates doesn't work.  But I it doesn't work on your sample data.  As a "workaround"  I would suggest trying the Advanced Filter.  The only drawback will be that it will always consider the first row as a header, so you may need to compensate for that.  Here is a routine that works on your sample data.  I chose to copy to a new destination, then overwrite the original, but you may wish to use a different scheme.

Also, if it works for you, you may want to disable screen updating while the macro is running.

By the way, the routine works with General formatting and mixed numeric and text data also. Probably no need to convert everything to text.

```
Sub RemDups()
    Dim R As Range
    Dim rDest As Range

Set R = Range("a1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

Set rDest = Range("D1")
rDest.EntireColumn.Clear

R.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , rDest, True

R.EntireColumn.Clear
Set rDest = Range(rDest, Cells(Rows.Count, rDest.Column).End(xlUp))
rDest.Copy R(1)
rDest.Clear

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a go at this:

**If your data size is <= 30k rows:** Elapse time around 0.2 sec comparable to *Excel's RemoveDuplicates*

```
Dim arr As Variant, i As Long
'~~> pass range values to array
With SheetCodename '~~> Change to suit
    arr = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)))
End With 
'~~> use Dictionary to remove dupes
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        .Item(CStr(arr(i))) = CStr(arr(i))
    Next
    SheetCodename.Range("A:A").ClearContents '~~> Clear source range
    '~~> Return unique items to range
    SheetCodename.Range("A1", "A" & .Count) = Application.Transpose(.Items)
End With
```

I tested this on your sample data and 17 unique values were returned.
For larger data sets though, this might fail due to Excel Memory shortcomings.

**Edit1:**
I got really interested to make this work in 100k rows and more so.
I then stumbled on [THIS](http://excelmontecarlo.com/24b_transpose_limitations_workarounds.html) and below is what I've come up with.
**Actual number of data tested:** 168091

```
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim arr() As Variant, i As Long, key, start

start = Timer
With Sheet4
    Set rng = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    rng.RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo
End With
Debug.Print Timer - start '3.585938 sec

start = Timer
With Sheet2
    Set rng = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
'~~> Use Dictionary to remove duplicates
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    '~~> need to loop through range since Array have limitations as well
    For Each cel In rng
        .Item(CStr(cel.Value2)) = CStr(cel.Value2)
    Next
    '~~> array limit workaround
    ReDim arr(.Count, 2): i = 0
    For Each key In .Keys
        arr(i, 0) = .Item(key)
        i = i + 1
    Next
    '~~> Return unique items to range
    Sheet2.Range("A:A").ClearContents
    Sheet2.Range("A1", "A" & .Count) = arr
End With
Debug.Print Timer - start '5.257813 sec
```

The result is the same with using *Excels RemoveDuplicates* (I mean the unique output).
There is a 1.671875 sec difference in performance but for me it is still manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample dataset was already formatted as text... I changed several rows to a number format and was able to remove the duplicates (without formatting everything as text) using the following code:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()

Dim r As Range
Dim w As Worksheet

Set w = ActiveSheet
Set r = w.Range("A1:A100000")

r.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=r.Offset(0, 1), Unique:=True

End Sub
```

The above code puts the unique values in column B, so you'd have to modify this to suit your needs. If you'd prefer the data remain in column A, you can create a temp sheet to put the unique values, delete your original data set, and then move the unique values back into the original sheet.

The above code assumes that you have a header for your dataset. I also don't know how well this will perform on large datasets... so you may need to do some testing to see if it will work for you.

---

**Edit**

I just tested this on 100K rows and it took ~50 seconds to finish... so I'm guessing this solution isn't viable. And I just saw you chose David's answer. :) I'll leave this up in case it helps someone else in the future.

**Edit 2**

I missed Ron's answer before I posted mine. We use the same function, but his answer has more functionality than mine.

Comment: Interesting.  What was your data set for the 100K rows?  I posted a similar solution using the AdvancedFilter a few hours ago, and I just tested it on a 110K row database, made by repeating the OP's data 5000 times, and it ran in well under a second.  With screenupdating off, it was almost instantaneous.  I'd be interested in testing it against your dataset.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Shoot! I'm sorry, I missed your answer when I looked through all the answers. My dataset was the OP's sample filled down to 100K rows. When I filled down, only half or so of the values were duplicates (only the text ended up duplicating). So the unique values list was ~50k rows.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I just tested 100k rows again, this time in a way that the output (unique values) list was equal to the original list. The procedure ran in less than a second as your tests did. The amount of time it takes is apparently related to the number of unique values in the test dataset (~50k vs 22).

Comment: OK, I get the same here.  I just set up a data set using RANDBETWEEN(1,50000) over 100K rows and got similar results to you.  Using a collection method, it took much less time.